# Kotlin recyclerview gave me null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

i started learing Kotlin after using Java, curently trying to create recyclerview using Kotlin, but everytime reach this code:

```
recyclerview!!.layoutManager = LinearlayoutManager(context)
```

inside a fragment, it always returns null for me, and by converting existing Java Code using converter in android studio returns error.Can anyone help me why this is always happened? code below is my current fragment code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notes.*
import java.sql.Timestamp

class NotesFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): NotesFragment {
            return NotesFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false)
        val messageList : MutableList<message> = prepareMessage()

        recycler_view!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recycler_view!!.adapter = NotesAdapter(context)   
        (recycler_view!!.adapter as NotesAdapter).setMessage(messageList)
        return view
    }

    private fun prepareMessage(): MutableList<message> {
        var messageList : MutableList<message> = ArrayList()
        for(i in 0..10){
            val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L
            val message = message(0,
                    "Judul Catatan ke $i",
                    resources.getString(R.string.lipsum),
                    timestamp
                    )
            messageList.add(message)
        }
        return messageList
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you even initializing the recyclerview object

Comment: i'm using kotlin android extensions @MohammedAtif

Comment: Your RecyclerView is inside view. You need to access it through view.

Comment: Even if you're using kotlin extensions, you need to access the recyclerview through the recently inflated view.

Comment: ah, you're right. thanks for noting @LeviAlbuquerque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

You should declare your recyclerview object, before accessing their properties.

.....

```
 private var recycler_view: RecyclerView? = null
```

.....

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false)

    recycler_view = view.findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_id)
    recycler_view?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recycler_view?.adapter = NotesAdapter(context)  

    val messageList : MutableList<message> = prepareMessage()
    (recycler_view?.adapter as NotesAdapter).setMessage(messageList)
    return view
}
```

Comment: this works! thanks! so basically i'm revert to standard way and not using kotlin android extensions i suppose?

Comment: Yeah, why is this happening? I have two activities and each one is a RecyclerView. One of them works without declaring the private far, the other one crashes. Can we resolve that instead of using an work-around?

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the views are not created yet in `onCreateView`. Since you are using `kotlinx.android.synthetic` you need to access it inside `onViewCreated`.Like this

```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
     val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false)
     return view
   }


  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    recycler_view = view.findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_id)
    recycler_view?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recycler_view?.adapter = NotesAdapter(context)

    val messageList : MutableList<message> = prepareMessage()
    (recycler_view?.adapter as NotesAdapter).setMessage(messageList)
}
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct answer. Don't give up guys

Answer (score 0):

have you declare your recylerview like this

```
 polishrecyler = view .findViewById<View>(R.id.polish_recyler) as RecyclerView
```

Comment: currently i'm using kotlin android extensions, sorry for not including import in the code

Answer (score 0):

I just now had a similar situation.

In my project, I have a `RecyclerView` working perfectly. In my case, it has five files involved: `Foo.kt` (the model), `FooList.kt` (the `AppCompatActivity` class), `FooListAdapter.kt`, `foo_list.xml` (the layout with the `RecyclerView`) and `foo_list_row.xml` (my custom row for the `ReyclerView`). Not sure if it's important or not, but the icon for `Foo.kt` is [image] while the icon for the `FooList.kt` and `FooListAdapter.kt` is [image]

I needed another RecyclerView, so I simply created five new files: `Bar.kt`, `BarList.kit`, `BarListAdapter.kit`, `bar_list.xml` and `bar_list_row.xml`. I copied/pasted the code from one to the other, and made the appropriate Foo->Bar changes in the code. This is when I got the same error as the OP. Looking in the `import` section, the import for `RecyclerView` was flagged as "superfluous". Odd.

Most of the suggested answers here is to declare the variable and use `findViewById` to reference it. But, my working `RecyclerView` doesn't do that, so why should it be necessary in the second `RecyclerView`? It doesn't make sense.

I continued to search and found this solution:

1. Save the code found in two files I had created manually (`BarList.kit`
   (the AppCompatActivity file) and the 'corresponding' `bar_list.xml`)
2. Delete those files.
3. Right-click on the package name and select `New > Activity > Empty Activity`. This re-created the files I had just deleted with exactly the same names.
4. Restore the code saved from step 1 to the appropriate files.

Now both my `RecyclerView`s work correctly.

I guess when you use the `New > Activity > Empty Activity`, Android Studio does some work in the background which is not done if you just create the files manually.